# span collapse not working when click random on it

Tags: jquery, accordion

here is my code:-

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne${count}" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne${count}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne${count}">
                    <h4 class="row panel-title">
                        <span class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 accordian-filegroupname">${fileGrp}</span> 
                        <span class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 accordian-filegroupeye">( Eye: ${getEyeTypeFromFileName(fileGrp)} )</span>
                        <span class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 accordian-filegroupeye">( Uploaded On: ${parentUploadedOn} )</span>
                        <span class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 accordian-filegroupicon"><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
```

and below is jQuery script:-

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function () {
       $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus')
           .closest('panel').siblings('panel')
           .find('i')
           .removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
   });
```

when user click on plus sign on UI for collapse it is working fine, but when user click randomly fast on it then sometime plus become minus and vise versa.
i want to keep minus sign when collapsed and plus sign when not collapsed on randomly fast click on it

Comment: We need to see some more of your html code

Comment: please make a working code snippet that reproduces your problem. Otherwise it's hard for us to debug your code

Comment: @jayant, did you try the answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it simple:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function () {
    $('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus');
});
```

The first line of the function will remove `fa-plus` class and add `fa-minus` to all `<i>` and then,
the 2nd line will add `fa-minus` class to only the clicked div's child `<i>`.

Please try this out. This should work.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, its working fine by this code:-

function toggleIcon(e) {

$(e.target)
    .prev('.panel-heading')
    .find(".accordion_icon")
    .toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
}
$('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
    $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);

Comment: ok, so the solution I provided is not helpful? If not, then I will consider deleting it.